# GLSL: Passing char array to fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have an `unsigned char[4096][4096]` array with intensity values, and I want to pass them properly to fragment shader.
Though it seems I need `glVertexAttribPointer()` (guess it is because I need data in fragment, not vertex shader) or `glTexImage2D()` with `type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, I couldn't achieve desired results.
Examples I've found did not help me either due to use of float/int vectors in them.

How can I access byte array data from fragment shaders?

Comment: You may use vertetxAttribute only if intensity data's are bound to vertices (which is surely not the case). So texture solution is ok, and you may access your data with normal sampling functions (... texture(...)).

Comment: You can usually only have 16-ish (how the number is calculated is fairly arcane) vertex attributes, so 4096x4096 would be going well beyond that even if it were appropriate to the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_R8UI` for `glTexImage2D()`'s `internalFormat` + `texelFetch()` for exact texel access in the shader.